# Options for the | (pipe) command

Tags: shell, unix

Does the Unix `|` (pipe) command have any options?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In short, **no**, but you can get the exit values of each of the commands in the pipe via `$PIPESTATUS`. You can change the behavior of it's return value via the shell option `shopt -s pipefail` and you can change how much is buffered from command to command via `ulimit -p`

Comment: `$PIPESTATUS` and `shopt -s pipefail` are bashisms but otherwise somewhat sensible. `ulimit -p` is also a bashism but fairly useless: it shows how much a program can write at once to a pipe such that the write cannot mix up with another write, but the actual buffer is usually larger; it is unlikely that you need this in a script but if you do, use `getconf PIPE_BUF /`.

Answer (score 4):

`|` is not a command and as such does not have any arguments. However the commands used around the pipe can take commands. Consult the manpages for those commands.

Answer (score 0):

`|` is not a command, rather a syntax construct interpreted by your shell. Thus you need to check your particular shell documentation to see if it supports some pipe specific options.

To better answer your question, can you tell which shell do you use and what are you trying to achieve?